# dhtmlx scheduler custom timeline

Tags: time, timeline, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

Currently i'm working on a project where i need to use dhtmlxSchedular whats new to me.

i'm struggling to change the timeline header view. For example this timeline: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/06_timeline/08_time_scale.html

Here you can see a timeline with a second time scale for one day
timescale 1: minutes
timescale 2: hours

What i want is a view for a week and one day has 10 hours. For example
Monday 12 dec till Sunday 18 dec
Where every day has 10 cells from 00:00 till 10:00.

So shortly saying, one day consists of 10 hours to be planned.

Is this possible with scheduler timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. To hide hours in the scale you need to use scheduler.ignore_timeline property.

[More info how to change the default time interval](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html#settingthetimeintervalfortheviewcells)
[Demo with Timeline scale you want to implement](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/ddce5a39)